# In Jenkins why do we see two different executors performing the same stage?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline (Jenkins version 2.138.3)
On Jenkins screen why do i see that the same stage say 'compile' is being executed on the same executor....?

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2qjJ.jpg)

**Example**: pipeline named 'multi-branch-pipeline-1' running on agent called 'agent-1' with three executors...here the stage 'stage-promotion' is being executed on the two different executors (2,3).

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'agent-1'}
     stages{    
        stage('compile') {
            agent {label 'agent-1'}
        }
        stage('stage-promotion') {
            agent {label 'agent-1'}
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, nested `agent` declarations work that way, the outer will keep its executor allocated and usable while the inner is running.

Since you use the same label (or rather direct addressing with agent name) it amounts to a 2nd executor on the same agent, there seems to be no logic for this rather unusual case, as you could just omit the agent declaration that amount to the same label.

Following will do the same as yours:

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'agent-1'}
     stages{    
        stage('compile') {
            // runs on agent-1
        }
        stage('stage-promotion') {
            // runs on agent-1
        }
    }   
}
```

Nested agents are very useful when you want to temporarily switch the machine in your pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'A'}
     stages{
        stage('start server') {            
            // runs on machine x with label A
        }    
        stage('test') {
            agent {label 'B'}
            // runs on machine y with label B
        }
        stage('stop server and archive logs') {
            // runs on **the same machine as in stage start server**, same workspace etc.
        }
    }   
}
```

Important part is, in the last stage, we can be sure to be on the same machine in the same workspace with no wait-time (i.e. executor contention) as in the first stage. If you use agent declarations inside the stages only, it could happen that we end up in a different machine than in the first stage if you have more than 1 agent with label A connected.